# sed regex not compatible with PHP regex

Tags: php, bash, sed

Here the text to change :

```
'db' => [
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bob',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'local',
        'password' => 'local',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
```

Result expected :

```
'db' => [
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bob',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'alice',
        'password' => 'local',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
```

sed command :

```
sed -E "s#('db'[ ]*=>[ ]*\[)((\n*?.*?|^\t*.*\n)*)('username'[ ]*=[ ]*>[ ]*)'.*'#\1\2\4'alice'#" textTochange.txt
```

My regex work on https://regex101.com/ without problem, work like a charm in PHP with preg_replace but no with sed :(

Comment: `php` uses a regex flavor that is not compatible with `sed`. Besides you are matching a multiline string. `perl` or `awk` are better suited for this.

Comment: thx for your help @anubhava ! I have edited my question with the answer :)

Comment: @GillesGrandguillaume Solutions should be put in Answers, not Questions. You're allowed to answer your own question.

Comment: @Barmar ok, done.

Answer (score 0):

Here the workaround :

```
perl -0pe "s#('db'[ ]*=>[ ]*\[)((\n*?.*?|^\t*.*\n)*)('username'[ ]*=[ ]*>[ ]*)'.*'#\1\2\4'alice'#m" textTochange.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

try with awk.

```
awk -v s1="'" '/db/{A=1} A && /username/{sub(/username.*/,"username" s1 "=> " s1 "alice" s1 ",",$0)} /],/{A=""} 1'   Input_file
```

Will add the explanation shortly too.

**EDIT1:** adding a non-one liner form of solution successfully too now.

```
awk -v s1="'" '
                /db/{
                        A=1
                    }
                A && /username/{
                                sub(/username.*/,"username" s1 "=> " s1 "alice" s1 ",",$0)
                               }
                /],/{
                        A=""
                    }
                1
              '   Input_file
```